# Python client generated from openapi-generator (.jar) throwing error when deserializing nested object

Tags: python, spring-boot, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I have api.json which looks something like this

```
 "type": "object",
 "properties": {
           "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uuid"
          },
          "config": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Configuration"
          }
      }
   }
.
.
.
"Configuration": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "softwareInstalled": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "connectivity": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
```

Now with my generated python client when I call entiyGet() which returns above entity as response. In case where configuration is not empty response deserializes fine but when Configuration is None deserialization throws error

```
    raise cls.__get_type_error(
openapi_client.exceptions.ApiTypeError: Invalid type. Required value type is frozendict and passed type was NoneClass at ['args[0]']['results'][0]['Configuration']
```

If I skip deserialization data comes fine but I need data in Dto. Can anyone help?

Tried using openjdk11